# Apply patches to python libraries

Tags: python, patch

I want to apply [patches](http://hg.secdev.org/scapy/) that the author of a Python library uploaded on his website. Is there any way to do this easily without resorting to doing it manually on each impacted line?

Something like:

```
$ applyPatch patchFile sourceCodeFile
```

Comment: Is the new version on pypi? How did you obtain and install the library originally? Those "patches" you're linking to aren't patches per se, they're a mercurial repository.

Comment: I obtained the library simply from synaptic in Ubuntu. I'm not familiar with mercurial repositories. Is there any way to automatically apply those patches I linked above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the raw patches (example: http://hg.secdev.org/scapy/raw-rev/7621f33286b9) you can apply them using `patch`, e.g.:

```
patch -p1 < 7621f33286b9.patch
```

You'll need to make sure that if they touch the same lines you apply them in the correct order; tools like quilt can help with this.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the Ubuntu package is actually in source form; if all it does is install an egg things will get ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the version via synaptic may not actually be the latest in the actual library's repositories, so you may find that some that patches aren't usable.

If you want to do work on a 3rd party library, then generally:

1. Create your own repository of the 3rd party's source control
2. Clone (or equiv.) the latest version
3. Amend, and push (or equiv.) locally
4. Patch yours against the original branch/whatever
5. Send patch or push if you had access